# Is this canned Asparagus any good?

Tags: spoilage, asparagus

What are the odd sprouts at the ends of them? Exp date is good.

I've seen this frequently now.  I usually just cut off the ends and eat it anyway.

[image: Asparagus from the can]

Comment: Yes, it's ok to eat green asparagus. No need to cut the end.

Answer (score 3):

The opening up is not really a sign of spoilage.  With Asparagus, what we are eating is really only the sprout.  The actual plant if allowed to grow is a branched plant like a fern.  They canned some that were starting to open up, a bit older than really should be picked.

*So yes, the entire asparagus is safe to eat.*

Comment: Now, if it is "good", well that one is opinion, and I will refrain from giving one on that.  (OK I think canned asparagus is an abomination, but that is not what you mean in the question.)  Thus comment only, not answer.  ;)

Comment: what do you mean by "opening up"? The one unusual thing I see in this picture are the weird white clumps, a bit like tonsiliths. I have never seen a similar thing on a raw asparagus, do you mean it is some kind of flower that comes when the tips open?